# Wait for form to finish updating in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on an Access application where I run a process that imports a bunch of text files into Access, and I want to display a progress meter for this process.

I've built a simple progress bar: I have a form with five rectangles and a text box. When one fifth of the text files finish importing, the text box displays "twenty percent of files imported" and one of the rectangles becomes visible. When the second fifth finishes it updates again and so on.

The problem I'm running into is that the form only gets updated at 60% and 100%. The code for the other increments works but the form is not being updated. I suspect that when I run a VBA statement like

```
Forms("ImportingData")!Box1.Visible = True
```

The script does not actually pause until the box becomes visible on the screen before it continues running. Its just changing the property internally or something. I have tried to fix this by having it pause for 1 second via

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)


Sub UpdateStatusForm(fifth As Integer)

    If fifth = 1 Then
        Forms("ImportingData")!PctComp.Caption = "20 percent of txt files imported"
        Forms("ImportingData")!Box1.Visible = True
    ElseIf fifth = 2 Then ...
    Sleep(1000)
End Sub
```

But it has not worked. Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: look at DoEvents. Not ideal but a good option when you want to update the GUI when a process is running

Comment: [Form.Repaint?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238071(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: @Philip yep, DoEvents works. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilipABarnes if you use that as an answer  we can see it has been addressed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at DoEvents. A good option when you want to update the GUI when a process is running